# Differences between a computation model and an abstract data type

Tags: computation-models, abstract-data-types

I am wondering about the difference between an abstract data type (ADT) and a computation model.

As I understand them:

- A computation model defines the basic unit of computation, that is, what can be done in a unit of time. The RAM model, for example, defines the basic data unit (the integer), their organization (the memory) and the primitive instruction to read, write and compute on these units.
- An ADT defines operations, axioms and domains. The operations are also basic "processing" units, and axioms define their semantics. The domains are the things we are manipulating.

I see a direct mapping: The operations of the ADT are the primitive instructions of the computation model, the axioms are the formal semantic of these instructions, and domains are the data unit defined by the computation model.

Would that make sense? Are these a single concept in disguise? Can I say the stack (the ADT) is a computation model of its own, albeit maybe a not so powerful one?

To my surprise, I have not yet found any book or article discussing this relationship. Thanks for any help or pointer.

Comment: With the case of ADTs, you will still have to define what "computation" means here. Usually, we mean that instances of the computational model (for example, the "multiply two numbers" turing machine, in the model of computation for turing machines) - are "solving" a language $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$. If you define a similar notion for ADTs, then sure! It will be a computational model

Comment: Thanks! I am not very familiar with Turing machines. Do you mean that ADTs miss the concept of "accepting state" (a la FSM)?

Comment: IMO, an ADT relates more to the structuring of data via aggregation (f.i. an ordered pair of numbers or a string of characters), whereas a computational model focuses on mathematical transformations and their cost (e.g. addition of numbers).